# UNION ALL Trick ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

This may be so easy, but I can not figure out how I can do.

so my code is like this

FOR example

```
SELECT id,total,total2
FROM  (select id,  0  AS total ,t1.total AS total2
       FROM table1 t1
       union ALL
       select id, t2.total AS total, 0 AS total2
       FRoM table2 t2)
```

it shows

```
id------total------totals
001      0           20
001      15          0
```

I would like to show like this

```
id------total------totals
001      15         20
```

How can I do that?

Thank you so much

Comment: Probably you could explain a bit the context of the request. Your desired outcome, as it is, could also result from a simple join between tables (see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b863/4))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do an aggregation afterwards:

```
SELECT id, sum(total) as total, sum(total2) as total2
FROM  (select id,  0  AS total ,t1.total AS total2
       FROM table1 t1
       union ALL
       select id, t2.total AS total, 0 AS total2
       FRoM table2 t2
     ) i
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dumping 0's into some columns as filler, you can use a WITH and subquery's to retrieve a sum on all records in the matching Id's from a distinct list of Id's.

```
;WITH GetIds AS (
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM table2
)
SELECT id,
(SELECT SUM(total) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = ids.id) AS total1,
(SELECT SUM(total) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = ids.id) AS total2
FROM GetIds ids
```